Elasticsearch Error: http client did not trust this server's certificate, closing connection Netty4HttpChannel
I have generated a self signed certificate to Elasticsearch using elasticsearch-certutil. Elasticsearch and kibana are working and running over HTTPS,I am trying to connect to ES using elasticsearch-client in my Angular project but I get the error net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID and Eleasticsearch logs shows me the error: "log.level": "WARN", "message":"http client did not trust this server's certificate, closing connection Netty4HttpChannel{localAddress=/172.24.0.2:9200, remoteAddress=/192.168.2.1:52916}"
my elasticsearch client:
  loadCA() {
    return this.http.get('assets/certs/ca.crt', {
      responseType: 'arraybuffer',
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',  
      })
      
    }).pipe(
      catchError(error => {
        console.error('Error loading CA certificate:', error);
        throw error;
      })
    ); 
  }

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.loadCA().subscribe(caCert => {
      const ca = [caCert];
      console.log(" enter");

      try {
      this.client = new Client({
        node: 'https://es1:9200',
        host: 'https://es1:9200',
        requestTimeout: 60000,
        sniffOnStart: false,
        cluster: "CG-cluster",
        auth: {
          username: 'elastic',
          password: 'teledia',
        },
        log: {
          level: 'debug',
        },
        tls: {
          ca: caCert,
          rejectUnauthorized: true,
        }, 
      });   
      } catch (error) {
        throw error;
      }
      console.log("called client");
    
      this.clientInitialized = true;
    });
 console.log("passed"); 
  }

my Elasticsearch.yml
network.host: 0.0.0.0
xpack.security.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: certificate
xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.path: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/elastic-certificates.p12
xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.path: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/elastic-certificates.p12
xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.http.ssl.keystore.path: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/elastic-certificates.p12
xpack.security.http.ssl.truststore.path: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/elastic-certificates.p12
xpack.security.http.ssl.verification_mode: certificate

http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
http.cors.allow-methods: OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
http.cors.allow-headers: X-Requested-With, X-Auth-Token, Content-Type, Content-Length
http.cors.allow-credentials: true


kibana.yml
server.port: 5601
server.host: "0.0.0.0"
server.name: "kibana"
elasticsearch.hosts: ["https://es1:9200"]
elasticsearch.username: "kibana"
elasticsearch.password: "teledia"
server.ssl.enabled: true
server.ssl.certificate: /usr/share/kibana/config/certs/instance/instance.crt
server.ssl.key: /usr/share/kibana/config/certs/instance/instance.key
elasticsearch.ssl.verificationMode: none
xpack.security.encryptionKey: "something_at_least_32_characters_stop_session_refresh"


The username and password are correct, I tried to disable security in elasticsearch.yml and tried with different certificates, nothing worked!

Hi, can you please share your kibana.yml as well? Thanks.

@MuratK.  I added kibana.yml, Thanks in advance
